# Can I set different background images for different monitors?

Tags: gnome

I use 2 displays - laptop's built-in 1024x768 panel and external attached 1600x1200 CRT. In XFCE I could set different backdrops to these 2. Can I in Gnome?

Answer (score 3):

It is not currently possible to do this with the default GNOME setup (ie. Nautilus, the file manager, manages the desktop wallpaper). There is [an idea in development](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/93/) to provide this functionality. It is possible to use other software, [such as compiz](http://anuragbansal.wordpress.com/2008/05/10/how-to-get-different-wallpapers-on-each-workspace-in-ubuntu/), to manage the wallpaper but I think this removes other desktop functionality (eg. files/folders/shortcuts on the desktop).