# How do I set different wallpapers for different virtual desktops?

Tags: gnome, compiz, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workspace specific wallpapers with Compiz?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4497/workspace-specific-wallpapers-with-compiz)

The Gnome & Compiz feature of having many virtual desktops is appreciable, but I would have liked to make them more particular one from another. So I would have liked to have different wallpapers, that is to say background images, on each desktop. Could you tell me how to do it ?

Please note that this is not a duplicate of [Can I set different background images for different monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5090/can-i-set-different-background-images-for-different-monitors).

Comment: It is a duplicate of [Workspace specific wallpapers with Compiz?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4497/workspace-specific-wallpapers-with-compiz)

Comment: A better duplicate which is update to Ubuntu 18.04 is [Is it possible to have a different background for each workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75998/)